# Convertir un Nodo a su selector de CSS

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de convertir un nodo a un selector de CSS, por ejemplo

```html
<div id="main">
    <p>...</p>
    <div>
        <p>Contenido</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Debería devolver el siguiente selector

```css
#main > div > p
```

Por ahora, lo que tengo implementado, funciona, pero solo para nodos con un *DOM Subtree* corto, cuando hay demasiados elementos anidados, el selector deja de obtener el elemento (usando `querySelector`)

```js
function nodeToSelector(n) {
    const index = [...document.querySelectorAll(n.tagName)].indexOf(n) + 1;
    if (n.id) {
        return "#"+n.id;
    }
    if (n.parentNode === document.body) {
        return n.tagName.toLowerCase() + ":nth-child("+index+")";
    } else {
        if (n === document.body) {
            return "body";
        } else {
            let lastSelector = '';
            let lastElem = n;
            while (lastElem.parentNode !== document.querySelector("html")) {
                let node = lastElem;
                if (node.id) {
                    lastSelector = "#"+node.id + " > " + lastSelector
                } else if (node.getAttribute("class")) {
                    const classIndex = [...node.parentNode.querySelectorAll("."+node.getAttribute("class").split(" ")[0])].indexOf(node) + 1;
                    const uniqueElem = [...node.parentNode.querySelectorAll("."+node.getAttribute("class").split(" ")[0])].length === 1;
                    lastSelector = "."+ node.getAttribute("class").split(" ")[0] + (uniqueElem ? " > " : ":nth-child("+classIndex+") > ") + lastSelector
                } else {
                    const index = [...node.parentNode.querySelectorAll(node.tagName)].indexOf(node) + 1;
                    const uniqueElem = [...node.parentNode.querySelectorAll(node.tagName)].length === 1;
                    lastSelector = node.tagName.toLowerCase() + (uniqueElem ? " > " : ":nth-child("+index+") > ") + lastSelector;
                }
                lastElem = lastElem.parentNode;
            }
            return lastSelector.trim().replace(/\>$/, "").trim();
        }
    }
}

document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(e => {
  console.log(
    nodeToSelector(e),
    document.querySelector(nodeToSelector(e))
  );
});
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
        <p>...</p>
        <div>
            <p>Contenido</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <p>....</p>
          </div>
          <div class="clasePrueba">
            <p>Contenido</p>
          </div>
          <div class="clasePrueba">
            <p>...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="clasePrueba">
            <p>...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Una pregunta que representa retos interesantes y que ayuda a aprender algo nuevo. ¡Genial, como siempre!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casi siempre, este tipo de problemas se solucionan con recursividad en vez de ciclos; para este caso, la búsqueda comienza en `p` y termina en `body` o el primer hijo de este, mientras que el orden para el selector CSS es al revés.

En cada llamada recursiva agrega al final el selector obtenido previamente.

Entre las modificaciones principales está el cambio de [nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) por [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type), porque el primero requiere que todos los hijos sean del mismo tipo y el segundo analiza solo los elementos con la etiqueta especificada. En CSS te dejé un par de ejemplos para ilustrarlo mejor.

Otros cambios:

- Si el parámetro recibido no está vacío, se agrega un espacio para evitar tener que hacerlo en cada llamada recursiva; no es necesario, pero sí conveniente
- Declaré algunas variables para simplificar el código
- Limité la búsqueda del elemento actual al contenedor padre, no tiene caso buscarlo en todo el documento
- Si solo hay un hijo dentro del contenedor, no tiene caso agregar modificadores como `nth-of-type`
- Es más fácil obtener las clases directamente desde la propiedad `classList` y generar el selector correspondiente
- Aunque lo conservé, te recomiendo eliminar el `>` en todos los selectores, porque teniendo `nth-of-type` parece redundante y es una de las cosas que se sugieren evitar al buscar [especificidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Creo que eso es lo más importante, a lo mejor se me escapa alguna otra cosa y, por supuesto, deberás probar diferentes escenarios y analizar el código para mejorar y optimizar la función.

```js
// Recibir como parámetro el selector previo
function nodeToSelector(n, prev = '') {
    if(prev != '') {
        // Agregar espacio a selector previo
        prev = ' ' + prev;
    }
    if(n.id) {
        return `#${n.id}${prev}`;
    }
    if(n === document.body) {
        return `body ${prev}`;
    }
    // Definir variables necesarias
    const parent = n.parentNode;
    const tagName = n.tagName.toLowerCase();
    // Limitar búsqueda al contenedor actual
    const items = parent.querySelectorAll(':scope > ' + tagName);
    if(items.length == 1) {
        // Es el único, no es necesario nth-of-type
        // ¿Se necesita clase o se puede omitir?
        if(parent === document.body) {
            return ' > ' + tagName + prev;
        }
        return nodeToSelector(parent, ' > ' + tagName + prev);
    }
    const index = [...items].indexOf(n) + 1;
    // Se debe agregar la etiqueta actual
    let ret = tagName;
    if(n.classList.length > 0) {
        // Agregar las clases necesarias
        ret += '.' + [...n.classList].join('.');
    }
    // Agregar modificador, por si hay más elementos
    ret += `:nth-of-type(${index})${prev}`
    if (parent === document.body) {
        return ret;
    }
    // Todavía no llegamos al cuerpo, llamada recursiva
    return nodeToSelector(parent, '> ' + ret);
}

document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(e => {
  console.log(
    nodeToSelector(e),
    document.querySelector(nodeToSelector(e))
  );
});
```

```css
/* Esto no funciona para contenido mixto */
#main > div:nth-child(1) {
    background:#aaa;
}
/* Esto sí funciona, no importa que haya P antes */
#main > div:nth-of-type(2) {
    background:#aaa;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
        <p>...</p>
        <p id="id-interno">ID de prueba</p>
        <div>
            <p id="id-interno-2">ID de prueba 2</p>
            <p>Contenido</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <p>....</p>
          </div>
          <div class="clasePrueba">
            <p>Contenido</p>
          </div>
          <div class="clasePrueba">
            <p>...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="clasePrueba con2clases">
            <p>...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```